# 3 columns with different numbers of rows using bootstrap-vue

Tags: multiple-columns, bootstrap-vue

I have this page that I am trying to convert from old school html to bootstrap-vue. I have 10 boxes that in large & medium mode should be 3 columns as pictured. When it goes down to small I need it to be 2 columns and xsmall would be 1 column. And the order needs to stay the same name, contact info, college, person status, for senate titles…etc.  Here is what I have so far. My rows are all the same height, which is no good. And the order on the output is close to good in large mode, but doesn’t match in the code which is annoying (ie, it would be nice if Name was 1st in the code and Contact info was 2nd etc). Maybe I shouldn’t be using b-row & b-col?

I am using bootstrap-vue 2.21.2 and bootstrap 4.5.3; and I am pretty new to bootstrap, obviously.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <b-container class="bv-edit-person-row">
        <b-row cols="1" cols-sm="3" cols-md="4" cols-lg="4">
            <b-col class="group-container">1 Name
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Initial">
            </b-col>
            <b-col class="group-container">6 Person Status
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Date of Initial Hire">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Title At Inital Hire">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Sep Date (Last Day)">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Sep Reason">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Comments">
            </b-col>
            <b-col class="group-container">9 Education
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="future input box">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="future input box">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="future input box">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="future input box">
            </b-col>
            <b-col class="group-container">7 Contact Info
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="future input box">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="future input box">
            </b-col>
            <b-col class="group-container">6 For Senate Titles
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="future input box">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="future input box">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="future input box">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="future input box">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="future input box">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="future input box">
            </b-col>
            <b-col class="group-container">10 Personal Data (AP Only)
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Legal Last/Surname">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Legal First/Given Name">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last 4 SSN">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="DOB">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Gender">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Citizenship">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Visa">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Visa End">
            </b-col>
            <b-col class="group-container">3 College
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="future checkboxes">
            </b-col>
            <b-col class="group-container">7 blank</b-col>
            <b-col class="group-container">11 Ethnicity
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="future check boxes">
            </b-col>
            <b-col class="group-container">4 System Info
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="future input box">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="future input box">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="future input box">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="future input box">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="future input box">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="future input box">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="future input box">
            </b-col>
            <b-col class="group-container">8 blank</b-col>
            <b-col class="group-container">12 Other
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Sab Credits Prior To Db">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Deceased">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="U 18 Quarters">
            </b-col>
        </b-row>
    </b-container>
</div>
</template>

<style >
    .group-container {
      border: 1px solid lightgrey;
      border-radius: 3px;
      margin: 10px;
      padding: 10px;
    }
</style>
```

I was hoping to get something like this:[image]